# Metropolis-Hastings algorithm, using a proposal distribution other than a Gaussian in Matlab

Tags: normal-distribution, matlab, markov-chain-montecarlo, metropolis-hastings, mathematical-statistics

I am currently working on my final year project for my mathematics degree which is based on giving an overview of the Metropolis-Hastings algorithm and some numerical examples. So far I have got some great results by using my proposal distribution as a Gaussian, and sampling from a few other distributions, however I am trying to go one step further by using a different proposal distribution.

So far I have got this code (I am using Matlab), however with limited resources online about using different proposals it is hard to tell if I am close at all, as in reality I am not too sure how to attempt this, (especially as this gives no useful data output so far).

It would be fantastic if someone could lend a hand if they know or forward me to some easily accessible information (I understand that I am not just asking coding advice, but Mathematics as well).

So, I want to sample from a Gaussian using a proposal distribution of a Laplace, this my code so far:

```
n = 1000;       %%%%number of iterations

x(1) = -3;      %%%%Generate a starting point

%%%%Target distribution: Gaussian:

strg = '1/(sqrt(2*pi*(sig)))*exp(-0.5*((x - mu)/sqrt(sig)).^2)';
tnorm = inline(strg, 'x', 'mu', 'sig');

mu = 1;    %%%%Gaussian Parameters (I will be estimating these from my markov chain x)
sig = 3;


%%%%Proposal distribution: Laplace:

strg = '(1/(2*b))*exp((-1)*abs(x - mu)/b)';
laplace = inline(strg, 'x', 'b', 'mu');

b = 2;       %%%%Laplace parameter, I will be using my values for y and x(i-1) for mu


%%%%Generate markov chain by acceptance-rejection

for i = 2:n

    %%%%Generate a candidate from the proposal distribution
    y = laplace(randn(1), b, x(i-1));

    %%%%Generate a uniform for comparison
    u = rand(1);

    alpha = min([1, (tnorm(y, mu, sig)*laplace(x(i-1), b, y))/(tnorm(x(i-1), mu, sig)*laplace(y, b, x(i-1)))]);


    if u <= alpha
        x(i) = y;
    else
        x(i) = x(i-1);
    end 
end
```

If anyone can tell me if the above is completely wrong/going about it in the wrong way, or there are just a few mistakes (I am very wary about my generation of 'y' in for the for loop being completely wrong) that would be fantastic.

Thanks, Tom

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as for the code, I think there is only one error which is the generation of random numbers according to Laplace distribution.

Replace

```
y = laplace(randn(1), b, x(i-1));
```

by (See [the Laplace distribution wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_distribution#Generating_random_variables_according_to_the_Laplace_distribution) to learn how to generate random Laplace distributed numbers before seeing my answer.)

```
u = rand()-0.5;
uu = b / sqrt(2); 
y = mu - uu * sign(u).* log(1- 2* abs(u));
```

One more thing, Laplace distribution is symmetric, so `laplace(x(i-1), b, y))=laplace(y, b, x(i-1))`. Therefore, when calculating your `alpha`, you can omit `laplace(x(i-1), b, y))/laplace(y, b, x(i-1))=1`.

There are a lot of books on MCMC approaches. But for a quick start, maybe [this paper](http://www.cs.princeton.edu/courses/archive/spr06/cos598C/papers/AndrieuFreitasDoucetJordan2003.pdf) and [this note](http://www.cc.gatech.edu/~lebanon/notes/metropolis.pdf) is good enough.

Comment: Thank you very much, thats a great answer, everything works now.

Comment: I should have noticed before that the Laplace distribution is symmetric, so that is something I can add to my write-up, thanks a lot!